# Adding GitHub Server to Jenkins via Groovy

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins

I'm trying to configure our Jenkins server via Groovy init scripts. I'm stuck on how to configure the [Github Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Github+Plugin). I want Jenkins to manage my hooks. So I need to add a [GitHubServerConfig](https://github.com/jenkinsci/github-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/github/config/GitHubServerConfig.java) to the [GitHubPluginConfig](https://github.com/jenkinsci/github-plugin/blob/d6d3695c132a9550fdaa23cc94f1b14309a3636f/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/github/config/GitHubPluginConfig.java) somehow. I already managed to set up the credentials. So I have this code so far:

```
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.github.config.GitHubPluginConfig
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.github.config.GitHubServerConfig

def github = new GitHubPluginConfig()
github.setConfigs([
  new GitHubServerConfig("github-access-token"),
])
github.save()
```

But this doesn't have any affect. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is "github-access-token" the id of your credential?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just stumbled over the answer myself:

```
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.github.config.GitHubPluginConfig
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.github.config.GitHubServerConfig

def github = jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.getExtensionList(GitHubPluginConfig.class)[0]
github.setConfigs([
  new GitHubServerConfig("github-access-token"),
])
github.save()
```